# Invalid Registry Endpoint pushing docker image

Tags: amazon-s3, docker

I built a docker container with docker 1.0, and tried to push it to a private docker registry mapped to s3, but it gives me "invalid registry endpoint".

```
docker push loca.lhost:5000/company/appname
2014/06/20 12:50:07 Error: Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://loca.lhost:5000/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connection reset by peer
```

The registry was started following settings similar to the example (adding aws region), and does respond if I do a telnet localhost 5000.

```
docker run \
         -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 \
         -e AWS_BUCKET=my-docker-images \
         -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
         -e AWS_KEY=AAAA \
         -e AWS_SECRET=BBBBBBB \
         -e AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 \
         -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy \
         -p 5000:5000 \
         registry &
```

s3 logging for the bucket:

```
8029384029384092830498 my-docker-images [16/Jun/2014:19:25:56 +0000] 123.123.123.127 arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/docker-image-manager C9976333A1EFBB7A REST.GET.BUCKET - "GET /?prefix=registry/repositories/&delimiter=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - 291 - 39 39 "-" "Boto/2.27.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.8.0-42-generic" -
```

Comment: I guess loca.lhost maps to 127.0.0.1. Is `curl http://loca.lhost:5000/v1/_ping` working?

Comment: The dot is there to avoid the posting rule.   Tried that and it returned empty reply from server.  With wget it returned no data received.    If I instead use 10.1.0.170 (eth0) or 10.1.0.174 (eth0:0) or 172.17.42.1 (docker0) it gives connection refused.

Comment: "docker ps" returns the following:   docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
570afdaa143e        registry:latest     /bin/sh -c 'exec doc   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   romantic_ptolemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was due to me specifying AWS_REGION  (eu-west-1) and the registry service failing part way through startup.

Taking that out, the registry server finishes initializing and starts listening on the port, and a curl request to the /_ping url returned a response.

https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry/issues/400

I was able to retrieve enough console information to debug this by putting the settings in a config.yml file,  setting loglevel to debug, then have docker running the registry image passing the config file rather than calling directly as I did above.